# how to make text wider in UITextView when rotate to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight

Tags: iphone, uitextview, rotation

I put some text into a UITextView. Now I wanna make the inside text occupy the additional space when device become horizon. But this way only make canvas fill in all the space not the text.

```
// This method is called by NSNotificationCenter when the device is rotated.
-(void) receivedRotate: (NSNotification*) notification
{
 UIDeviceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

 if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
 {
  self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
  self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 416, 320);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using xibs and interface builder for your views?  If so, you should be able to use [struts and springs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/Layout/Layout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH19-SW17) to have the UITextView resize automatically.

If not, you'll have to reset the UITextView's size programmatically in the `receivedRotate:` method.